# Change Default Program for a specific folder

Tags: windows-7, default-programs

I do not know if this is possible (I suspect that it isn't), but can you change the default program for a file type for only a specific folder and the folder's sub-folders in Windows 7?

What I am trying to do is set the html files in a specific folder to open in Notepad++ by default, and everywhere else, open in Chrome (which is the current default).

I do know how to change the global default program for a file extension, but that is not what I am trying to do in this case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In a word: Impossible

The registry cant be customised for an individual folder it is all or nothing.

Comment: That was what I had suspected.  I wasn't sure if there was a program that somehow got around it.